# Convert canvas or control points to SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I am developing a drawing app, and now I want to add a function which creates SVG from my canvas or control points. (I save the mouse coordinates for each drawing step).

```
canvasElement.toDataURL("image/svg+xml"); // -- doesn't work
```

One condition - don't use external libs.

I understand, that it is possible to generate an SVG file in Javascript like:

```
var mysvg = "<svg>"; for(something) { mysvg += "something"; } //etc
```

But I don't think that it is good way.

Can you advise anything?

Comment: This would be fairly complicated. You're right that `toDataURL('image/svg+xml')` doesn't work. It never did in any browser, as far as I remember. What kind of functionality does your drawing app have? If it's simple shapes, then you can translate those to SVG `<path>`'s. If you're supporting gradients, images, etc. you need to translate each one of those individually into corresponding elements in SVG.

Comment: Actually the form arnt simple, ok, I will try. But anyway will wait for other way solving this trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem by generating SVG file. I translated all my canvas drawing functions into SVG drawing tags.

Something like that:

```
function exportSVG() {
    var svg = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>';
svg += '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">';
svg += '<svg width="1065px" height="529px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">';

for(var i=0; i<myPoints.length; i++) {
   svg += "M"+myPoints.x[i]+","+myPoints.y[i]+" ";
   svg += "L"+myPoints.x[i+1]+","+myPoints.y[i+1];
   svg += '" fill="none" stroke="rgb('+color+')" stroke-opacity="'+opacity+'" stroke-width="'+size+'px" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />';
}
svg += "</svg>";
}
```

So, in svg variable there will be SVG file generated from Canvas.
Thanks everybody!

Comment: How would this even work? You're missing the opening tag in your for loop. What is that tag supposed to be? <path or <line ?