# Can my HTML5 Canvas code be converted to SVG?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I have the following example code:

```
    function drawCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("logoText");
        var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
        c.lineWidth = 1;
        c.lineStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        c.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 40);
        c.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        c.font = "22px 'HelveticaNeue-Light','Helvetica Neue Light','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif"
        c.fillText("Test", 20, 45);
        hexstring1 = "\u2610";
        c.fillText(hexstring1, 20, 70);
    }
```

If I assume use of browsers that support both SVG and Canvas then how could I convert this code to use SVG.

Also what would there be any advantage or disadvantage to using SVG over Canvas?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571294/method-to-convert-html5-canvas-to-svg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918597/convert-canvas-or-control-points-to-svg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SVG is tag based like HTML itself. So you have to insert DOM nodes inside an `SVG` tag. Your example translates roughly to the below code.

You may create this in JavaScript the same way like any other nodes, but make sure to use `document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect' );` to insert the nodes instead of the usual `document.createElement( 'div' );`.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="40" style="stroke: #FFFFFF; stroke-width: 1px" />
  <text x="20" y="45" style="fill: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light','Helvetica Neue Light','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; font-size: 22px">Test</text>
  <text x="20" y="70" style="fill: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light','Helvetica Neue Light','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; font-size: 22px">&#9744;</text>

</svg>
```

There are two advantages of using SVG over canvas:

- Your images scale much better. There are much less artifacts if you enlarge your image.
- You can make your elements "clickable". Attach the same events like in HTML to any element in SVG. So you can, e.g., make some sort of a custom button using SVG, attach a click handler and use it as a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert from canvas to svg directly. You can store the canvas drawing commands in a stack, afterwards you can generate a path data string, or use the DOM Interface. Look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) for the structure of path data

Comment: Sorry. What I mean by convert is just to recode in SVG. Maybe I did not explain very well.

Comment: It is a good idea, use this library that does just that: http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/

Comment: @michelpm looks like a good library, since unifying the apis can be a pain in the back. On the other hand, I used nearly always only one of the technologies, so dealing with one API was enough…